# Google Play Console App Transfer Default Currency Problem

Tags: android, google-play, app-transfer

We selled one of our app. However our account's default currency is TRY and the target account's currency is USD.

We are getting this error:

"The default currency of the new developer account is different to the existing developer account."

When we asked this to Google their reply was:

"The target account for your app transfer is using a different default currency. In order to proceed, you'll need to define a price for your app and its in-app products that uses the target account's default currency."

However we could not manage to that. When we try to define new/update in-app product or subscription it is still showing in TRY.

Does anyone have this problem too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In  Paid apps or apps with in-app products

If you're transferring paid apps or apps with in-app products, your target account needs to have an active [payments-profile](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3092739)

If you're using a different default currency on your target account, here are two conditions that apply to your transfer:
In-app purchases only: You need to add a price in the new default currency for each in-app product. After your app is transferred to your target account, the app will be unpublished until you publish it again. Once you've verified the new prices on your target account, publish the app again.

Ref:[android developer answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3092739)
[SO question on migrating payment account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347049/what-are-the-prerequisite-required-before-transferring-app-from-one-playstore-ac)

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply.

However,

"You need to add a price in the new default currency for each in-app product"

We can't do that. When we try to update or create new inapp product in current account, we still get prices in TRY. We cant create new products in USD.